# What is the correct, cross-platform way to sleep for less than a second?

Tags: php, cross-platform, sleep

I want my script's execution to pause for about a half of a second.

While looking at the PHP documentation's user comments, I found multiple functions that purported to be able to do this. But, for each function, there was at least one poster who claimed that it was wrong and that they had a better way of doing it, and so-on and so-forth.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first function I would try is [`usleep`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php). From the docs:

> Delays program execution for the given number of micro seconds.

Comment: It's always dependent on the OS, in some UNIX flavors you can't tell your app to sleep for < 1 second because of timeslicing granularity. In some these are implemented using signals :)

Comment: Yeah, that confused me. One person suggested using sockets to perform the delay on a Windows system, but according to the docs (http://php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php#refsect1-function.usleep-changelog), the function works on Windows as of PHP 5.

Comment: @Justin Ethier: Thanks for the link; the function looks like it will do exactly what I want.